# Screen recording asks permission every time in android version 12 or above

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile, screen-recording

Thanks for your attention about my trouble.
I am working with android + java & kotlin app.
It needs to be screen recorded but it asks permission every time in android version 12 or above.

Screen Record Permission Request

[image: 1]

I hope this would ask only one time for permission request.
I've seen [XRecorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=videoeditor.videorecorder.screenrecorder) does require once for screen recording permission not every time.
Isn't there anyway to make my app to ask only one time for permission request.
Wish someone would help me to solve this.

Comment: The media projection APIs require user permission. Historically, with a well-written app, you need to obtain permission once per process. Perhaps some rules changed in Android 12, but the need for a permission prompt has been there since Android 5.0.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know there would be required permission since android 5.0, but what makes me annoying is requiring every time. One time is tolerable but each time asking is nervous.

Comment: Well, it *should* make people nervous. I think the permission prompt changed over the years -- what you show now helps users make informed decisions about whether they want your app to have this power.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, you can save the result of media projection intent and reuse it during the same application process session. That is how most applications overcome this issue.

But be aware that it is more a hack than a solution because the docs do not guarantee it. In contrast, it says you can not reuse it. So use it at your own risk.

From my observations, it will work almost everywhere except some Xiaomi and Huawei devices. You can add them to ignore list and ask every time. Another good idea will be to add a try-catch when reusing an intent, so you can request permission again if the intent is expired.

Context: we use this hack in an application with millions of active users, so it has some credibility.

Code snippet to get the idea, but not production ready:

```
object MediaProjectionIntentHolder {
    
    var intent: Intent? = null

}

class ScreenRecordingFragment : Fragment() {
    

    // A user clicked button and this function is called
    private fun startScreenRecording() {
        val intent = MediaProjectionIntentHolder.intent
        // You can check Huawei / Xiaomi devices here to ask permission every time
        if (intent != null) {
            recordScreen(intent)
        } else {
            requestPermission()
        }
    }

    private fun recordScreen(intent: Intent) {
        // Actual screen recording start
    }

    private showError() {
        // show error
    }


    private fun requestPermission() {
        val service = requireContext().getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE) as MediaProjectionManager
        val intent = service.createScreenCaptureIntent()

        val screenRecordingSupported = context.packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0).isNotEmpty()

        if (screenRecordingSupported) {
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE)
        } else {
            showError()
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                MediaProjectionIntentHolder.intent = data
                recordScreen(data)
            } else {
                showError()
            }
        }
    }

    private companion object {
        private consta val REQUEST_CODE = 42
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your advice.
but i wanna know where to save the result of media project intent

Comment: @KittyKagaya, you can save the intent in memory anywhere because it is only valid while the process is alive. For example, save it in the camera fragment as a variable. Or, as in our application, save it in a Kotlin object.

Comment: thanks for your kind attention.
would you kindly send me the code snippet so I can get bright picture.

Comment: Hello, Ivan Shafran.
I hope you would send me the code snippet so I can see how to save the result of intent.

Comment: @KittyKagaya Hello, Kitty! I updated the answer. Please check the attached snippet for the idea. If it solves your problem, you can mark the answer as accepted, so other users can rely on it, also. If it's not, do let me know, if I can help you further

Comment: Big thanks to you. it works well as you expected. hope you would take attention on my question later again